# window.opener undefined in JavaScript popup after redirect

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with a website that displays a payment dialog using window.open().

The page in the popup redirects to a different domain that redirects back to a result page. On the result page, I try to set a property on `window.opener` to signal that the payment is ok.

This works for some users. Other users, however, get an error saying that `window.opener` is undefined.

The problem can the recreated using these simple pages:

**index.html**
(Opens the popup)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Popup" onclick="openPaymentWindow();" />

    <div id="result" style="background-color: silver;"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openPaymentWindow() {
            win = window.open('popup.html', 'popup');            
        }
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.html**
(Redirects to a different domain)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit();">
    <form action="http://[other_domain]/payment.html">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**payment.html**
(Redirects back to the original domain)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit();">
    <form action="http://[original_domain]/result.html">
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

**result.html**
(Sets a property on the index page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Call top" onclick="callTop();" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callTop() {
            // Here, window.opener (and top.opener) is undefined for some users
            window.opener.document.getElementById('result').style.background = 'green';
        }
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Since not all users are affected, my guess is that it has to do with some security settings. But I simply cannot figure out where to find them - or how to replicate the error on my own pc.

Comment: I think window.opener will fail if the two pages are not under the same domain. You can check the following for an alternative solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876830/window-opener-cross-domain-call

Comment: `window.opener` is a property of a document opened from main window. If the pop-up loads a new document itself, then it's not loaded from main window, and don't have said property anymore. Even despite of the domain being the same.

Comment: Please go through given link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120534/window-opener-is-null-after-redirect`

Comment: I see that this should not be possible. But still this works when I test it myself and for hundreds of other users. That's at bit odd.

Comment: @NeerajDubey In the link you are refering to, the asker apparently solves it by added his own page before the PayPal page. That's exactly what I am doing... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120534/window-opener-is-null-after-redirect#comment8550035_7120534)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve what you want, it may not be very clean though. 
So `index.html` and `result.html` are on the same domain and script in `index.html` contains a reference to window object of a popup. This means that if you set some property on `window` object in `result.html` you will be able to read that property on `win` variable in `index.html`. The only problem is you don't know when exactly the property is being set, so you will have to use setInterval to check it.

**Index.html**

```
function openPaymentWindow() {
    var win = window.open('popup.html', 'popup');

    var successPoller = setInterval(function() {
        try {
            if(typeof win.PAYMENT_SUCESS !== 'undefined' && win.PAYMENT_SUCESS) {
                document.getElementById('result').style.background = 'green';
                clearInterval(successPoller);
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            // handle error
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

**result.html**

```
 function callTop() {
      window.PAYMENT_SUCCESS = true;  
 }
```