# Checking that popup has redirected back to opener's domain/port/protocol in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect, popup, same-origin-policy

I do a `window.open(popupURL)` to make a popup.  The popup redirects to some other site which redirects back to my site.  I use `window.setInterval()` to watch for when the popup gets back to my site.  But I can't find a way to gracefully observe that condition.  It makes sense to me, for instance, to evaluate the expression

```
popup.document.domain === window.document.domain
```

but it seems that I'm not allowed to read `popup.document`, as it gives me an error related to the fact that the opener is using HTTP while the popup is using HTTPS.  I thought that maybe I could use `popup.location` somehow, so as to avoid asking for that sensitive foreign document, but trying to read anything out of `popup.location` produces a similar error.  I'm not even allowed to read `popup.location.protocol`!  Is the foreign site's choice of HTTP versus HTTPS really such a big secret?

Anyway I can get around these problems by swallowing those errors in an empty catch block.  Then my domain check above seems to work.  But is there a way that doesn't involve the ugly catch block?

Comment: Just so that I understand, you have a site A which pops up a site B which then redirects to site A but over SSL?

Comment: Site A makes the popup which opens onto a page on site A that ends up redirecting it to site B, which later redirects it back to site A.  All requests to site A use the protocol HTTP.  Some (probably all) requests to site B use the protocol HTTPS.  (Also, I glossed over the popup's first request to A in my question because it isn't really involved in the problem I guess.  Basically I want a script in the opening window to detect the popup's transition from B back to A...  which I'm doing successfully, but I'm using a catch block and that feels like a potentially bad hack.)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding two functions to the window A. A function that will be triggered onload, and that will call another function that will do whatever you want. Not sure how it's gonna work once the popup is redirected from B to A - that is if it will have access to window.opener though...

In pseudo code:

```
//This code will go in the window A, which is also loaded in a popup after a redirect.
window.onload = function(){
  if( window.opener && !window.opener.closed ){//This is to make sure only the popup will call it.
    doSomething();
  }
}

function doSomething(){ //Do soemthing }
```

Comment: I moved to the strategy I'm using now after something like that failed.  I ran a little test just now and it seemed to work though...  I think maybe relying on the popup's opener after the popup has redirected is sketchy, and sometimes works but sometimes doesn't?  That's the impression I got at the time, from my own experience and from pages such as this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469837/window-opener-undefined-in-javascript-popup-after-redirect